# NoReverseMatch error in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, web

Using the Django admin to add users I get the error:

> NoReverseMatch at /admin/usuarios/user/add/ Reverse for
>   'usuarios_user_change' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/usuarios/user/(.+)/$']

I'm using AbastractBaseUser and UserAdmin

All I have for the admin in URLConf is

```
url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls))
```